# Remove \ from end of value

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (BrowserName.ToUpper().Contains("FIREFOX"))
    privateModeParam = " -private-window";
string extraspeech = "\"";
string both = BrowserName + extraspeech + privateModeParam;
Process.Start(both, URLFromDB);
```

When it run's it returns the following value:

```
BrowserName = "c:\\program files\\mozilla firefox\\firefox.exe"
both = "c:\\program files\\mozilla firefox\\firefox.exe\" -private-window"
privateModeParam = " -private-window"
```

What I need to do is, trim the `\` from `both` string because it won't open firefox with that back slash.

I should add if I simply do:

```
string both = BrowserName + privateModeParam;
```

the value returned is "c:\program files\mozilla firefox\firefox.exe\ -private-window"
what won't open Firefox

Comment: why using `extraspeech` then ? just don't use it.

Comment: I think the extra backslash is added because you're adding `extraspeech` to `BrowserName` when assigning `both`. Couldn't you just not add `extraspeech` there?

Comment: I think there's a double quote missing at the beginning of `c:\\program files\\mozilla firefox\\firefox.exe"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What causes your problems is the double-quote (`"`), not the back-slash. There is no backslash at this position in the string, it's only displayed like that by your debugger because c# uses `\` to escape things like `"` inside string literals.

So your problem seems to be that you forgot to add `extraspeech` *before* the executable, too:

```
string both = extraspeech + BrowserName + extraspeech + privateModeParam;
```

or better

```
string both = $"\"{BrowserName}\" {privateModeParam}"; // C#6
string both = string.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", BrowserName, privateModeParam); // pre C#6
```

---

*Update*:

But the real problem here seems to be that you pass one command line argument in the `fileName` parameter and one via the `arguments` parameter.

You should actually call `Process.Start` like that:

```
Process.Start(BrowserName, $"{privateModeParam} {URLFromDb}");
```

Simply pass all arguments in side the `arguments` parameter. Then there is also no need to wrap the executable in double-quotes as it is the only string in the `fileName` argument. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start) for more information about the parameters to `Process.Start()`.

Comment: For both of these it returns the value of "\"c:\\program files\\mozilla firefox\\firefox.exe\"  -private-window" and it still fails to open Firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
if (BrowserName.EndsWith("\\")){
    BrowserName = BrowserName.Substring(0, BrowserName.Length - 1);
}
```

or

```
both = both.Replace("\\\"", "");
```

may fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use Substring:
                MyString = MyString.Substring(0, MyString.Length - 1);